# Which of these user fields can be retrieved from Facebook, and how?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm doing a website where the client wants to retrieve as much of a user's profile info as possible, and then pre-fill the sign up form of our website with this info.

These are the fields that our sign up form has:

- First & Last name
- Gender (male/female)
- Post code
- Date of birth
- Email

1) Which of these fields can be retrieved from facebook after a user authorizes our app?

2) Which permissions do we need to ask for in the 'scope' paramater when redirecting the user to facebook's login dailog?

3) Which API method(s) are used to retrieve the above info once a user has authorized the app and we have received the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All of them should be available (I am not 100% sure about postcode though). Note: They are only available to fetch if the user specified them at all.
2. For first/last name and gender - `user_about_me`. For Birth Date - `user_birthday`. For his postcode - `user
   -address`. For his email - `email`.
3. I'd go with [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), which can be used by the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), with the [fb.data.query](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.data.query/) method.